# And + Or query using elastic search REST API

Tags: elasticsearch

How do we combine AND/OR Query in elastic search. For Eg, Below are the documents we have

```
{"title": "MI2", "brand": "Xiomi","operatingSystem": "Android"},
{"title": "Nexus","brand": "Google","operatingSystem": "Android"},
{"title": "Samsung Note","brand": "Samsung","operatingSystem": "Android"},
{"title": "Samsung Galaxy","brand": "Samsung","operatingSystem": "Android"}
```

Now How do we query Android phones from either Samsung or Xiomi.

( operatingSystem == "Android" ) AND ( brand == "Samsung" OR  brand == "Xiomi")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND/OR Logic can be applied as a Filter.

Filters in elasticsearch will evaluate before a query is executed, so if you need to apply this logic to a call that also contains a string query, it will still be efficient and applicable.

As your OR code is evaluating the **same** property, in this case brand, you can use the Terms Filter within an AND statement. Your ES call would look like the following:

```
{
   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "your search string"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": { "operatingSystem": "Android" }
          },
          {
            "terms": { "brand": ["Samsung", "Xiomi"] }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may see the documentation for Terms [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html). The default is a boolean OR, returning documents who match any of the values provided.

To expand upon your question, if you wish the second part to evaluate an OR statement that is on **different** properties, for example with your data structure using title and brand, it would look as follows:

```
{
   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "your search string"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": { "operatingSystem": "Android" }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": { "brand": "Xiomi" }
              },
              {
                "term": { "title": "Samsung Note" }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The latter is equivalent to:

```
( operatingSystem == "Android" ) AND ( title == "Samsung Note" OR brand == "Xiomi")
```